# Facebook web crawler

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler

I am attempting to build a web crawler to sign into FaceBook and check the online status of some family members for a project I'm building for my parents. Upon searching, I found that this is attainable through FQL queries on friend online presence, but it seems that this will be removed around April of this year. So I thought that maybe I can just do a basic crawler myself in python that will get the HTML info from online friends in my chat, but when trying to print out the HTML code after attempting to log in, it returns a very large amount of jumbled HTML and javascript that mentions "BigPipe." I see that BigPipe breaks pages into pagelets but I'm a little confused on what to make of this information.

So my questions are, does anyone know of another way to get online statuses other than the FQL queries, has anyone else attempted to crawl Facebook, has anyone attempted to crawl any site with this BigPipe response?

Thank you in advance,
Jake

Comment: There is no way to do it using the API except FQL. And crawling Facebook is not allowed according to https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to write a FireFox extension. You will not be able to scrape FB without JavaScript.  That pretty much rules out most traditional scraping methods.

Comment: FireFox extension is an interesting idea. Yeah I was thinking that JavaScript was going to have to come into play at some point here. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Using PyQt4.QtWebKit will help to deal with javascript.

Here some basic usage of it : [webkit-pyqt-rendering-web-pages](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/webkit-pyqt-rendering-web-pages/)

Documentation: [PyQt4-qtwebkit.html](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtwebkit.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just finished my school project which requires user data from Facebook group members. I used a web crawling tool - [Octoparse](http://www.octoparse.com/?qu) for data extraction, it's a non-programming application and can be used to crawl different types of data on Facebook. You can go to this tutorial:[Facebook Scraping Case Study | Scraping Facebook Groups](http://www.octoparse.com/tutorial/facebook-scraping-case-study-scraping-facebook-groups/#sthash.2QCjjj0w.dpuf/?qu)